# Insert data where Multiple Foreign keys are in SQL server table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I have three Tables:

- Teachers

  - PK: `A_pk`
- Students

  - `PK: B_pk`
- Post

  - `PK: C_pk`
  - `FK: A_pk`
  - `FK: B_pk`

I have a Website page where users write different posts.

When teachers post in that group, I will insert data into the `Post` table like this:

`A_pk = teacherName`
`C_pk = Post_text`

When students post in that group, I will insert data into the `Post` table like this:

`B_pk = studentName`
`C_pk = Post_text.`

Reason is that I want to keep record which user posted data in my group.

Now the Question is how to insert record in Post table?

Comment: Disabling FK is not a good practice, so you have to insert the missing PK on table A and table B before inserting in table C. There is no way around that. Maybe we can help you with your tables design? Why wouldn't you have values for table A and B if you (or someone) forced the FK Constraint in C?

Comment: Why are you inserting foreign keys that don't have corresponding primary keys anyway?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please read it again

Comment: as per what I understood.you can have nullable FK.so when you insert for student then A_PK can be null and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one field in your table be a foreign key to two different tables.  What you need to do is change your data structure to either hold your students and teachers in the same table and use that primary key in your `Post` table, or to have two columns in your `Post` table - one for the `Teacher` primary key and one for the `Student` primary key and populate the appropriate one based on who made the post.

There is absolutely no need nor reason to have the ID of two different tables within the same field.  Doing so would be bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Finally--- I found the Solution.

Actually its very simple... Like you can have nullable FK.so when you insert for student then A_PK can be null and vice versa. –

*If teacher posted data in group than*

> if(A_pk != null) { Insert A_pk and Insert C_pk }

*If student posted data in group than*

> else if(B_pk != null) { Insert B_pk and Insert C_pk }

Thanks alot Sir
***KumarHarsh 1 hour ago***